# Framewok7 how to prevent router.back to remove cached page

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

I use with framework7 initialize property that called : domCache: true.
the loading page is work fine:

```
mainView.router.load({ pageName: dataPageName });
```

but the back page remove the page from the DOM. and this is not fit to the cached dialog .

```
mainView.router.back({ pageName: dataPageName });
```

how do i prevent the back to remove my page from DOM ?

Answer (score 0):

Try uniqueHistory and pushState true while initializing myApp object.

uniqueHistory: true,
pushState: true